# node.js stubbing AWS S3 method in request spec with sinon

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sinon, aws-sdk

I've got an `express` based app running on `node.js 0.12.2` which uses the `s3.headBucket` method from `aws-sdk 2.1.22` to return a JSON response depending upon whether a particular bucket exists or not.

I've been struggling to directly stub out the call to `s3.headBucket` with sinon.  I've managed to work around this by creating an s3wrapper module which just requires the `aws-sdk` and instantiates and returns the `s3` variable, however, I'm sure this can be done without using the wrapper module and can instead be stubbed directly with sinon, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Below is the currently working code (with the wrapper module `s3wrapper.js` which I'd like to remove and handle the stubbing in my `status_router_spec.js` file). In other words, I'd like to be able to call `s3.headBucket({Bucket: 'whatever' ...` instead of `s3wrapper.headBucket({Bucket: ' ...` and be able to stub out this `s3.headBucket` call with my own response.

**status_router_spec.js**

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    request = require('request'),
    myHelper = require('../request_helper')

var expect = chai.expect

var s3wrapper = require('../../helpers/s3wrapper')

describe('My router', function () {
  describe('checking the service status', function () {
    var headBucketStub

    beforeEach(function () {
      headBucketStub = sinon.stub(s3wrapper, 'headBucket')
    })

    afterEach(function () {
      s3wrapper.headBucket.restore()
    })

    describe('when no errors are returned', function () {
      it('returns healthy response', function (done) {
        // pass null to represent no errors
        headBucketStub.yields(null)

        request.get(myHelper.appUrl('/status'), function (err, resp, body) {
          if (err) { done(err) }
          expect(JSON.parse(body)).to.deep.eql({
            healthy: true,
            message: 'success'
          })
          done()
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

**s3wrapper.js**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var s3 = new AWS.S3()

module.exports = s3
```

**status_router.js**

```
var Router = require('express').Router

var s3wrapper = require('../helpers/s3wrapper.js')

var router = new Router()

function statusHandler (req, res) {     
  s3wrapper.headBucket({Bucket: 'some-bucket-id'}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({ healthy: false, message: err })
    } else {
      return res.json({ healthy: true, message: 'success' })
    }
  })
}

router.get(/^\/status\/?$/, statusHandler)

module.exports = router
```

Comment: The stubbing of `s3wrapper.headBucket` looks good to me (although, you can drop the reference and just call `s3wrapper.headBucketStub.yields(null)`), but what about `request.get`? That needs to be stubbed as well and the callback yielded.

Comment: The reason I'm using `headBucketStub.yields(null)` explicitly in the test is because I've actually got a few different tests and I want the `headBucket` method to return a different value for each test. As for the `request.get`, I actually want that as well, since this is a request test, so I'm sending an actual request to a server instance which has been set up for the test.  After further investigation, I'm able to get rid of the `s3wrapper` if I instead export the `s3` variable from my `status_router` module, although this isn't really that much of an improvement

Comment: I got the same problem, but it doesn't work even if I use a wrapper.

Comment: @kunde try posting your code and maybe someone can offer some help.  I believe the reason I was having difficulty stubbing out the call was because  in a request spec, you need to start a server, and it looked like I was stubbing the S3 library if you were to make a direct call to it, but once it went through the server, the request reached the unstubbed version.  Creating an S3 wrapper allowed me to stub out the S3 calls, and I also switched to using the supertest module for running my server.

Comment: @adamc turns out that I was using the wrapper wrong. I only required the wrapper in the test, but not in the module that I needed to test. After analyzing the situation, it makes sense that you can stub the wrapped s3 instance, because without the wrapper, you're trying to stub a different instance. I don't know how to do it without the wrapper, but it works fine for me like this.

Comment: I got the same problem. Can you try posting your solution so as users like me will learn something from it?

Comment: @ippomakunochi I've posted the solution we ended up using, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question for the benefit of @ippomakunochi who requested a follow up response.

We ended up using [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) to directly set a stub on the s3 library. For example, we stubbed the `getObject` call for the s3 library using the following:

```
s3stub = { getObject: sinon.stub(), listObjects: sinon.stub() }
revert = s3.__set__('s3', s3stub)
```

Here's the complete code:

**../../../build/app/helpers/s3**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

module.exports = {
  get: function get(options, callback) {
    var requestOptions = { Bucket: module.exports.bucket(), Key: options.productId + '.json' };

    s3.getObject(requestOptions, function (err, data) {
      if (err) { // handle err }

        try {
          var productData = JSON.parse(data.Body);
        } catch (e) {
          // handle error
        }
        return callback(null, productData);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**test/unit/app/helpers/s3_spec.js**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var chai = require('chai')
var sinon = require('sinon')
var sinonChai = require('sinon-chai')
var chaiSubset = require('chai-subset')
var rewire = require('rewire')

var s3 = rewire('../../../build/app/helpers/s3')

chai.use(chaiSubset)
chai.use(sinonChai)

var expect = chai.expect

describe('S3', function () {
  var s3stub, revert

  beforeEach(function () {
    s3stub = { getObject: sinon.stub(), listObjects: sinon.stub() }
    revert = s3.__set__('s3', s3stub)
  })

  afterEach(function () {
    revert()
  })

  describe('#get', function () {
    context('when no errors are returned by s3', function () {
      it('returns a product', function (done) {
        var productResponse = helper.fixture.body('product.json')
        s3stub.getObject.yields(null, productResponse)

        s3.get({ productId: '1234' }, function (err, res) {
          expect(err).to.not.exist

          expect(res).to.containSubset({name: 'long sleeve shirt', 'retailer_code': 'retailer-1'})
          done()
        })
      })
    })

    context('when s3 returns a NoSuchKey error', function () {
      it('returns a NotFoundError', function (done) {
        var s3Error = AWS.util.error(new Error(), { name: 'NoSuchKey' })
        s3stub.getObject.yields(s3Error)

        s3.get({ productId: '1234' }, function (err) {
          expect(err.message).to.eql('1234 is not found in s3')
          expect(err.output.statusCode).to.eql(404)
          done()
        })
      })
    })
  })
```